# Converting WPF project - Framework 3.5 to 4.0?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, wpf-4.0

Currently my project delveoped in WPF with Framework 3.5 and I am planning to convertert from 3.5 to 4.0? Is there anything to be done to successfully convert from 3.5 to 4.0 or is it normal conversio  procedure?. Is there any preformance degradation will be there in some controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upgrade the project file and create a new solution file for 4.0 version. You need to update the `TargetFrameworkVersion` and `ToolsVersion` in project file. There is a project file upgrader utility available in code project. As far as I know there would be no performance degradation at all.

http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/macros/SolutionConverter.aspx